# Email output node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE TestFlow_Compute1
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
         CALL CopyMessageHeaders();
        --CALL CopyEntireMessage();

        SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.To = 'abcd123@gmail.com';
        SET OutputRoot.EmailOutputHeader.From = 'xyz456@gmail.com';
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.Email.SMTPServer ='smtpout.secureserver.net:25';

        DECLARE sid INTEGER InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.eid;
        DECLARE track CHARACTER InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.etid;
        DECLARE sname CHARACTER InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.ename;
        DECLARE sorg CHARACTER InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.eorg;
        DECLARE ssal INTEGER InputRoot.XMLNSC.emp.esal;

       SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Data.Result.cty=PASSTHRU('SELECT city from ITGDB.mssusr14.collector where targetid='||track TO Database.mss);
       SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Data.Result.id1=sid;
       SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Data.Result.nme=sname;
       SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Data.Result.or=sorg;
       SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.Data.Result.sl=ssal;

        RETURN TRUE;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyMessageHeaders() BEGIN
        DECLARE I INTEGER 1;
        DECLARE J INTEGER;

        SET J = CARDINALITY(InputRoot.*[]);

        WHILE I < J DO
            SET OutputRoot.*[I] = InputRoot.*[I];
            SET I = I + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END;

    CREATE PROCEDURE CopyEntireMessage() BEGIN
        SET OutputRoot = InputRoot;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

I used above esql code to send data to email output node, but it is not propagating.Could you please suggest me what is the mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a PROPAGATE call.

```
     PROPAGATE TO TERMINAL 'out' DELETE NONE;
```

For Example.  Hopefully this helps get you moving.  I've also had to RETURN FALSE; rather than TRUE to prevent an additional message over the terminal.